# How to delete old records while keeping certain history

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has `a`, `b`, and `timestamp` fields.

Table is getting very long, and I would like to remove records older than a year, with some exceptions - I need to keep:

- at least 4 latest records for each value of `a`, regardless how old
- at least 4 latest records for each value of `b`, regardless how old

For example, in the following case:

```
=> select a, count(*) from Data group by a;
 a  | count
----+-------
 A  |     4
 B  |    12
 C  |    17

=> select a, count(*) from Data where timestamp > now() - INTERVAL '1 year' group by a;
 a  | count
----+-------
 A  |     0
 B  |     8
 C  |    11

=> select b, count(*) from Data group by b;
 b  | count
----+-------
 1  |     5
 2  |    13
 3  |    15

=> select b, count(*) from Data where timestamp > now() - INTERVAL '1 year' group by b;
 b  | count
----+-------
 1  |     3
 2  |     8
 3  |    10
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
=> select a, count(*) from Data group by a;
 a  | count
----+-------
 A  |     4
 B  |     8   (possibly more for b=1 records)
 C  |    11   (possibly more for b=1 records)
    
=> select b, count(*) from Data group by b;
 b  | count
----+-------
 1  |     4
 2  |     8   (possibly more for a='A' records)
 3  |    10   (possibly more for a='A' records)
```

In this case:

- I want to keep all 4 records with `a='A'`, even though they are all older than a year.
- For records with `b=1` I want to keep the latest 4 and remove the oldest one.
- For records with `a='B'` or `a='C'` or `b=2` or `b=3`, I don't need to worry about records older than a year.

Of course, my actual data has 1000 different values for the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) function (manual) - all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/__K4py0E).

```
WItH cte AS
(  
  SELECT 
    a, b, ts, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY ts DESC) AS rn
  FROM data
)
SELECT 
  a, b, ts
FROM
  cte
WHERE RN <= 4;
```

Window functions are **very** powerful and well worth investing time in learning - you will be repaid many times over!

I put some of my own sample data in the fiddle, but you should be able to follow the logic. Note the sorting by `DESC`.

A couple of points

- the sample data in the fiddle is not exactly yours, you might think about providing one yourself in future with your questions,
- it's not a good idea to use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) as variable names - it's error prone, makes reading your SQL difficult to read and also, it'll be non-portable. Some systems require double-quotes (") for such variables, others the back-tick (`) and some, like PostgreSQL don't require either.

  This is too much of a mess - just don't use keywords and use `snake_case` (lower case with extra words concatenated using an underscore (_). Here is an **excellent** SQL style guide - the important thing is to pick a style and** stick to it!

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the code by *Vérace*...
I think the solution should utilize two individual `ROW_NUMBER()` columns for `a` and `b` respectively. If you use just one column for `a, b` combined, you will keep at least four entries for any possible combination of `a` and `b`.

The result would look something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(  
  SELECT 
    a, b, ts, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY ts DESC) AS rn1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY ts DESC) AS rn2
  FROM data
)
SELECT 
  a, b, ts
FROM
  cte
WHERE (rn1 <= 4)
  OR (rn2 <= 4)
  OR ts > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year';
```

Here is the corresponding [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fH9mZkCY).

BTW: I think the question is a bit misleading. At first you mention that for every value of `a` and for every value of `b` the latest four entries have to be kept regardless of their timestamp. Then you go on and say that

> For records with a='B' or a='C' or b=2 or b=3, I don't need to worry about records older than a year.